# Singular Parametrizations of Curves

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Say $C$ is the upper half of the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, oriented to the right. If $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, and $\mathbf{r}(t)$, $a \leq t \leq b$ is a parametrization of $C$, we can define:

$$\int_Cfds = \int_a^b f(\mathbf{r}(t))|\mathbf{r}'(t)|\, dt$$

In particular, we should demand that $\mathbf{r}(t):[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is an injective $C^1$ function with nonzero derivative everywhere, which maps $a$ to $(-1,0)$ and $b$ to $(1,0)$. Any parametrization satisfying these requirements will give the same answer.

A common way to parametrize this curve is the following:

$$\mathbf{r}(t) = (t,\sqrt{1 - t^2}); \quad -1 \leq t \leq 1$$

The derivative of this curve is:

$$\mathbf{r}'(t) = (1,\frac{t}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}})$$

This seems to be problematic, since the derivative is unbounded and undefined at the endpoints. However, the RHS of the top equation seems to give coherent answers for continuous $f$, naively applying the FTC (or, more rigorously, treating the integral as an improper Riemann integral).

So my **QUESTION:** As long as the parametrization is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, will everything work out? ie, Will the integral always be well-defined and equal to an integral using a 'better' parametrization? What about in higher dimensions- If a surface is parametrized by $\mathbf{r}(u,v)$, where $(u,v)$ lies in some closed region (say a rectangle), is $\mathbf{r}$ `allowed' to be differentiable only in the interior?

If it helps, my motivation comes from teaching a multivariable calculus class and not wanting to say wrong things (a nearly impossible task).